# Different Beer with Different food

Tags: taste, pairing

I was wondering if there are certain combinations of beer and food go perfect together in my own experience I have found that **Negra Modelo** goes really well with Mexican food

do you guys know of any other really good combinations ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Beer and food pairings have an entire subculture, not unlike wine. On both [Ratebeer](http://www.ratebeer.com/Forums/Forum-7.htm) and [Beer Advocate](http://www.beeradvocate.com/community/forums/beer-food.40/), there are entire forums dedicated to beer and food pairing. Honestly, there are an infinite number of combinations.

One thing I've heard is that a lot of chefs really like pale lagers. Not because the pale lagers themselves are all that amazing (personally, I'm not a fan of them), but they present a neutral palate, which allows them to pair well with most dishes.

Personally, two of my favorite pairings are hoppy IPAs with spicy food, and imperial stouts with desserts (especially if they are chocolate-based). IPAs complement the spice and help cut the heat of the spicy food. And the dark roastiness of the imperial stouts really complements the sweetness of dessert.

The infographic below is from [craftbeer.com](http://www.craftbeer.com/food/pairing/pairing-chart) and contains their recommendations on food and beer pairing. I tend to like what it suggests.

[image: Craftbeer.com's guide to food and beer pairing]

Comment: Thanks for the information I too enjoy stouts with deserts you gave me a good amount to read up on

Answer (score 1):

For a good spicy curry I like significantly hop-forward beer, like a big IPA.

Answer (score 1):

Modelo is a nice beer to use to make a Chavela/Michelada. Doesn't leave a nasty after taste. At times I love to enjoy a nice cold modelo with some tajin.